# set offsetRange() function in pyspark rdd kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I successfully integrated kafka and spark.
I want send streaming from kafka to spark.and now I am able to send stream to spark.I want this stream in RDD so I used createRDD() function to create rdds.
But I got only some masseges from kafka in rdd. because it depend on offset range.So please anyone can tell me how to set offsetRange() in kafka-spark CreateRDD() function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in your code snippet

```
// Import dependencies and create kafka params as in Create Direct Stream

    val offsetRanges = Array(
      // topic, partition, inclusive starting offset, exclusive ending offset
      OffsetRange("test", 0, 0, 100),
      OffsetRange("test", 1, 0, 100)
    )

    val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String](sparkContext, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
```

[Spark Kafka Integration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

According to documentation: 
[pyspark kafka streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#module-pyspark.streaming.kafka)

First set offsetranges for kafka topic partion using

```
pyspark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange(topic, partition, fromOffset, untilOffset)
```

Initialization looks like:

```
fromOffset = 0
untilOffset = 10
partition = 0
topic = 'topic'
offset = OffsetRange(topic, partition, fromOffset, untilOffset)
offsets = [offset]
```

Then you will be able create your RDD

```
kafkaRDD = KafkaUtils.createRDD(sc, kafkaParams, offsets)
```

Comment: yas but how to use it in pyspark

Comment: what is version of spark are you using ?

Comment: I using spark 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code snippet for Kafka Offset handling .

```
topicpartion = TopicAndPartition(var_topic_src_name, var_partition)
fromoffset = {topicpartion: var_offset}
print(fromoffset)

kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,\
                                   [var_topic_src_name],\
                                   var_kafka_parms_src,\
                                   valueDecoder=serializer.decode_message,\
                                   fromOffsets = fromoffset)
```